How can I find basics about staking system?
I need basics about staking system.I can't find any information about solana staking system in solana documentations.I need help.

Here are a few resources that give different info on Staking on Solana:

Staking and Inflation FAQ (solana.com)
Staking on Solana (solana.com)
Solana Staking 101 (marinade.finance)
How to Stake SOL (quicknode.com)
Staking - Solana Cookbook (solanacookbook.com)
Solana Staking Dashboard (solanacompass.com)

